# Is it possible to connect to a wifi access point using iOS 4 SDK

Tags: iphone

I was wondering if it is possible to list and connect to nearby wifi access points programmatically. The `Reachability` sample only addresses if the device is connected to wifi or 3G/edge, and using something like the `CaptiveNetwork` API allows me to register if wifi authentication should be handled by a custom application but does not contain anything relating to the wifi connection aspect. Ideally I am looking for something like `android.net.wifi.WifiManager` from the Android SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the public API.

There used to be Apps in the App Store which did this using private methods, but they have been removed by Apple.